# What is the subject in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar, verb, subject

> (1) Davids Freund Frank hört auch gern Jazz.

Here we are talking about David or Frank or jazz, I am so confused. I feel like the subject should be jazz because here we have auch.

> (2) Hörst du auch gern Jazz?

Here I am asked *do you like jazz?* So the subject should be myself which in German is *mich*, right?

> (3) Freitags geht er oft in einen Jazzklub.

Here we are talking about *he* which is what in German?

Comment: I don't see why "auch" would indicate any case. "Er und sie auch nehmen den Apfel und auch die Birne vom Tisch und auch aus dem Karton."

Comment: @Robert, it should be "Er und sie _nehmen auch_ den Apfel und auch die Birne vom Tisch und auch aus dem Karton."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neben der Frage „Wer oder was“ interessiert noch das Verb, auf wen bezieht sich das Verb?

> (1) Davids Freund Frank hört auch gern Jazz.

Da wir nur ein Verb haben, ist die Antwort trivial: Frank hört … – Wer oder was hört (auch gern) Jazz? Frank.

Schwieriger wird es bei den anderen Beispielen auch nicht. Mehrere Verben können die Sache verkomplizieren:

> (1a) David hat einen Freund, Frank, der auch gerne Jazz hört.

Wer oder was hat einen Freund? David. Der Hauptsatz ist „David hat …“, während das Jazzhören den Freund näher bestimmt, daher wäre hier David das Subjekt.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you try to find the subject in German you ask **Wer?** or **Was?**. Which can be roughly translated with who or what, however due to the German grammar, “who” has several translations that cannot directly be reflected in the English language (**Wer** — Who was that? (nominativ) **Wen** — Who do you ask? (akkusativ)

In your examples it would be:

> (1) Davids Freund Frank hört auch gern Jazz.

**Wer** hört auch gerne Jazz? Who likes to listen to jazz?

Answer: (Davids Freund) Frank

If you want to get the other parts of the sentence you ask

- Wessen Freund hört gerne Jazz? (Genitiv) Answer: Davids Freund
- Wen oder was hört Davids Freund Frank gerne? (Akkusativ) Answer: Jazz

> (2) Hörst du auch gern Jazz?

**Wer** hört gerne Jazz? Who likes to listen to jazz (i.e., who is asked?)

Answer: Du

> (3) Freitags geht er oft in einen Jazzclub

**Wer** geht Freitags oft in einen Jazzclub? Who goes to the jazz club on Fridays?

Answer: Er (He — which is the pronoun which can be used instead of a 3rd person Singular like *Frank, mein Freund,* etc.)

Comment: Ah sorry, used "who is asked?" and translated to "Wen fragst du?". Corrected that mistake

Comment: The translation of "auch" in the sentence "Wer hört *auch* gerne Jazz?" is missing: "Who likes to listen to jazz *, too*?"